# Can't clear textarea once Text has changed in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, textarea

Simple use case:
Textarea and Button, when the button is clicked, the text in the Textarea changes.

Sample:
JS

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#t1').text('test');
});
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="t1" cols="10" rows="5"></textarea><button>Clear</button>
```

[Fiddler example](http://jsfiddle.net/uQ825/)

However when I change the button and then click the button the Text doesn't change **in Chrome and Firefeox** (in IE10 it works as). (Tested in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox)

When I debugg it and, check the text of the textarea, it displayes the correct valeu.

Is this a browser bug, jQuery bug or am I missing something?

Comment: use .val('works') instead, see working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uQ825/1/

Comment: thanks, but why does text work the first time and then it fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `textarea` element has a value, so use `val('')` to set it, like this:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#t1').val('test');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uQ825/2/)

Comment: thanks, that solves it, but why does text work the first time and then it fails?

Comment: I would imagine it's a peculiarity to do with the internal method browsers have of getting the text inside the textarea on page initialisation.

Comment: Setting the text sets the default value of the textarea.  Setting the default value of form controls will change the value only if the value has never been changed from the default value to start with.  That's why you're seeing it work before you edit the text but not after.